# Sum of time difference between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table which records every status change of an entity

```
id      recordTime        Status
ID1 2014-03-01 11:33:00 Disconnected  
ID1 2014-03-01 12:13:00 Connected  
ID2 2014-03-01 12:21:00 Connected  
ID1 2014-03-01 12:24:00 Disconnected  
ID1 2014-03-01 12:29:00 Connected  
ID2 2014-03-01 12:40:00 Disconnected  
ID2 2014-03-01 13:03:00 Connected  
ID2 2014-03-01 13:13:00 Disconnected  
ID2 2014-03-01 13:29:00 Connected  
ID1 2014-03-01 13:30:00 Disconnected
```

I need to calculate the total inactive time i.e time between 'Connected' and last 'Disconnected' status per ID for a given time window.

For above table and time range of 2014-03-01 11:00:00 to 2014-03-01 14:00:00 the output should be:

```
ID  InactiveTime
ID1  01:15:00
ID2  02:00:00
```

Comment: Are you sure about your about your desired output ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the next row for any given `id` has the opposite status?

Comment: @Houari: Output is correct if you consider the given time range `2014-03-01 11:00:00 to 2014-03-01 14:00:00`.

Comment: @Erwin, yes the status toggles definitely for each entry.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter oups i see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special difficulty is not to miss the time spans to the outer time frame.
Assuming that the next row for any given `id` always has the opposite status.
Using the column name `ts` instead of `recordTime`:

```
WITH span AS (
   SELECT '2014-03-01 13:00'::timestamp AS s_from  -- start of time range
        , '2014-03-01 14:00'::timestamp AS s_to    -- end of time range
   )
, cte AS (
   SELECT id, ts, status, s_to
        , lead(ts, 1, s_from) OVER w AS span_start
        , first_value(ts)     OVER w AS last_ts
   FROM   span s
   JOIN   tbl  t ON t.ts BETWEEN s.s_from AND s.s_to
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts DESC)
   )
SELECT id, sum(time_disconnected)::text AS total_disconnected
FROM  (
   SELECT id, ts - span_start AS time_disconnected
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  status = 'Connected'

   UNION  ALL  
   SELECT id, s_to - ts
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  status = 'Disconnected'
   AND    ts = last_ts
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Returns intervals as requested.
IDs without entries in the selected time range don't show up. You would have to query them additionally.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f91d3/5)
Note: I cast the resulting `total_disconnected` to `text` in the fiddle, because the type `interval` is displayed in a terrible format.

#### Add IDs without entry in the selected time frame

<sup>Per request in comment.</sup>
Add to the query above (before the final `ORDER BY 1`):

```
...
UNION  ALL
SELECT id, total_disconnected
   FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
          t.id, t.status, (s.s_to - s.s_from)::text AS total_disconnected
   FROM   span     s
   JOIN   tbl      t ON t.ts < s.s_from  -- only from before time range
   LEFT   JOIN cte c USING (id)
   WHERE  c.id IS NULL         -- not represented in selected time frame
   ORDER  BY t.id, t.ts DESC   -- only the latest entry
   ) sub
WHERE  status = 'Disconnected' -- only if disconnected
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f91d3/6)

Now, only IDs without entries in **or before** the selected time range don't show up.

Comment: Why does it shows messed results if I change the time range from 11:00 to 14:00 to 13:00 to 14:00?

Comment: @Sandeep: My first version was not prepared for rows outside the time range. Consider the updated version with updated fiddle.

Comment: For your comment "IDs without entries in the selected time range don't show up. You would have to query them additionally.", what would be your  suggestion? What do u think about my answer which is basically an enhanced version of yours which also considers "IDs without entries in the selected time"

Comment: @Sandeep: Consider the addendum addressing that.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand your question [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b36ef/1)

```
select id, sum(diff) as inactive
from (
    select
        recordtime,
        recordTime -
            lag(recordTime, 1, recordTime)
            over(
                partition by id
                order by recordTime
            )
        as diff,
        status,
        id
    from t
) s
where status = 'Connected'
group by id
order by id
;
 id | inactive 
----+----------
  1 | 00:45:00
  2 | 00:39:00
```

Could you explain your desired output?

Comment: @Houari: Also missed the same essential detail. ;)

Comment: As Erwin mentioned in his answer "The special difficulty is not to miss the time spans to the outer time frame."

Answer (score 0):

```
select id , sum(diff) inactif_time
from
(
SELECT id, "recordTime", "Status" ,LEAD("recordTime") OVER(PARTITION BY id order by "recordTime" ),LEAD("recordTime") OVER(PARTITION BY id order by "recordTime" ) - "recordTime" diff
  FROM my_table
) B 
where "Status" = 'Disconnected'
group by id
```

But it outputs:

```
"ID1";"00:45:00"
"ID2";"00:39:00"
```